# previous checked check box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

http://jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/gy8EQ/20/

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
 if (this.checked) {
     var lastChecked = $(this).prevAll(":checked:first");
     if (this.value == lastChecked.val()) {
         alert("previous checked box has same value");
     }
 }
});
```

The problem is it only works right to left try the other direction? Trying to do  if the value does not equal `if (this.value != lastChecked.val()) { alert("previous checked box has same value"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
var lastChecked = $(this).siblings(":checked:first");
```

It will find next and previous checkboxes.

Comment: @tyler. You're not saying what you'tr trying to do, so it looks find by me, I just don't understand what is fine there... GIVE THE DETAILS!